# What exactly is this type?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between const int*, const int * const, int const *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const)

Can someone explain this type to me?

```
char const * const blah;
```

I would have expected it to be written something like: `const char *`. what does the const post the type mean? e.g. `int const foo`.

and then, what does the first statement mean?

Comment: Where is the semicolon? Where is the variable or function or ... name?

Comment: sorry, fixed. the main problem is my brain is totally fried.

Comment: Without any assignment this type is *useless*. You can't change the const `blah` after you declared it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constant pointer to constant char. You can't change the address it points to and you can't change the character(s) at the end of it.

Comment: I'm confused as to why it isn't const int * const

Comment: @SirYakalot : `const int foo` is identical to `int const foo`. By similar logic, `const int * const foo` is identical to `int const * const foo`.

Comment: I never new you could put the const before OR after. huh. what about const int const *?

Comment: @SirYakalot: That's an error - you can only specify `const` once. You could write `const int volatile` if you really wanted to.

Comment: You could even argue that it's best in general to always put the const *after* the type, because you read complicated types from the inside out, and because in this particular instance, the const relating the the pointer *has* to go after the *. However, nobody actually bothers with this.

Answer (score 2):

```
char const * const ptr = "Hello";
```

`ptr` is a const pointer to a constant character(s). Which means neither `ptr` nor the data it is pointing a can be modified. Since pointer it self is constant type, it needs to be intialized because it later can not be reassigned.

```
char const * const laterPtr; // Wrong.
```